# Incompatible types with Math.min in BlueJ

Tags: java, compiler-errors, min

I'm having "incompatible types: int  cannot be converted to java.lang.String" error at Math.min(stop1, Math.min(stop2, stop3)) when I try to compile. I can't figure out why I'm having this issue since I wouldn't expect to change integers to strings to run min() method. Any thought?

```
import edu.duke.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class TagFinder {

    public String findStopIndex(String dna, int index) {
        int stop1 = dna.indexOf("tag", index);
        if (stop1 == -1 || (stop1 - index) % 3 != 0) {
            stop1 = dna.length();
        }
        int stop2 = dna.indexOf("tga", index);
        if (stop2 == -1 || (stop2 - index) % 3 != 0) {
            stop2 = dna.length();
        }
        int stop3 = dna.indexOf("taa", index);
        if (stop3 == -1 || (stop3 - index) % 3 != 0){
            stop3 = dna.length();
        }
        return Math.min(stop1, Math.min(stop2, stop3)); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to return an `int` value here :

```
return Math.min(stop1, Math.min(stop2, stop3));
```

But the return type of `findStopIndex` is a `String` .

If you really need a `String` as a return type, just convert the `int` to a `String` :

```
return String.valueOf(Math.min(stop1, Math.min(stop2, stop3)));
```

If you don't, change the method signature to return the correct type :

```
public int findStopIndex(String dna, int index)
```